# insert rows vba excel with conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I want to insert a row whenever the cell (j, 1) is different from (j-1,1), this is my code:

```
Sub colocar_Linha()
ultima_linha = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row

    i = 3

    While i <= ultima_linha

        If Not Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1) Then

            Rows(i).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown

        End If

        i = i + 1

    Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed the last line value grab
and the if condition
Following your comment, I added 1 to i after the row insersion
This way, once a row is in inserted, the counter will go with it, and skip the new blank row. since the entire range increased, then ultima_linha should also increase :

```
Sub colocar_Linha()
ultima_linha = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").CurrenRegion.Rows.count

i = 3

While i <= ultima_linha

    If Not (Cells(i, 1).value = Cells(i - 1, 1). value) Then

        Rows(i).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown

        i = i + 1
        ultima_linha = ultima_linha + 1;


    End If

    i = i + 1

Wend
End Sub
```